# Django Search function

Tags: python, html, django, web

How do I provide a search bar in django? My code is as follows...

home.html

```
<form method='GET' action="">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search posts"/>
<input type="submit"  value="Search"/>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
posts = Post.objects.all()
search_term = ''

if 'search' in request.GET:
    search_term = request.GET['search']
    posts = posts.filter(text__icontains=search_term)

context = {
    'posts': posts,
    'search-term': search_term
}

return render(request, 'feed/home.html', context)
```

Comment: A search bar? I think it's up to you to design it the way you want with some css/js stuff

Comment: [follow this link for query search using class-based views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61167874/10999814)

Answer (score 8):

You likely need a function-based view. This is probably a duplicate or semi-related question.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Posts #or whatever your model is

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q','')
    #The empty string handles an empty "request"
    if query:
            queryset = (Q(text__icontains=query))
            #I assume "text" is a field in your model
            #i.e., text = model.TextField()
            #Use | if searching multiple fields, i.e., 
            #queryset = (Q(text__icontains=query))|(Q(other__icontains=query))
            results = Posts.objects.filter(queryset).distinct()
    else:
       results = []
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'results':results, 'query':query})

    #You can also set context = {'results':results, 'query':query} after 
    #the else: (same indentation as return statement), and 
    #use render(request, 'home.html', context) if you prefer.
```

You should be able come up with your own error-handling or redirects as needed. Your urls.py will probably have to be something like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('feed/', views.search, name='home'),
    #'feed/' being the name of desired url, 'views.search' the 
    #name of your func-based view, and "name='home'" the template
    #you're using.
]
```

And your search bar would prob need to look like:

```
<form method='GET' action=".">
    #I believe lowercase get also works
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search posts"/>
    <input type="submit"  value="{{ query|escape }}"/>
</form>
```

EDIT: I forgot that you'll want to access the results and display them in your template (you can drop this in under the form for now). Something like:

```
{% if query %}
    {% if results %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in results %}
        <li>{{ item|escape }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
       <p>Query returned no results.</p>
       #SO is formatting "Query" in HTML for some reason. Nonetheless...
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```