# Add ?q=search+term in django url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I want to integrate elastic search with django but first I need to get a nice parameter in url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?q=search+term
```

urls.py (of the view)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('?q=', SearchIndexView.as_view(), name="search-index"),
]
```

urls.py (of the app)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('u/', include('user.urls')),
    path('search', include('search.urls')),
]
```

That is what I have so far but I cant figure out how to make it work.
I want to use tha path() and not url() if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define [url query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in `urls.py`. You can keep the url like this:

```
path('', SearchIndexView.as_view(), name="search-index"),
```

and in `SearchIndexView` you can do it like this:

```
q = request.GET.get('q')
```

Comment: Ok thanks, do I have to 'clean' the get value as well so its safe to search on?

Comment: I don't think it would be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

HTML FORM

```
<form action="{%url 'search' %}"  method="get">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
   <button  type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

urls

```
path('search/',views.search,name='search')
```

views

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
      print("do your stuff here")
```

Answer (score 2):

keep your url like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', SearchIndexView.as_view(), name="search-index"),
]
```

in the html form

```
<form method='GET'>
```

and in the `input put name="q"`

Answer (score 1):

**in Django generic views you can create search views as follows for model Blog**

```
class SearchResultView(ClientMixin, TemplateView):
template_name = 'clienttemplates/clientsearchresult.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        lookup = Q(title__icontains=query)
        search_list = Blog.objects.filter(lookup)
        context["slist"] = searchlist
    return context
```

**in html simply put name='q' inside input tag**

```
<input type="text" class="search-field " placeholder="Search Blog..." value="" name='q'>
```

**in urls.py**

```
path('search/result', SearchResultView.as_view(), name="searchresult"),
```

in clientsearchresult.html you can simply add

```
 {% if slist %}

             {% for blog in slist %}
               {{blog.title|title}}
               {{bog.content|safe}}
               {% endfor %}... and so on 
               {% endif %}
```